# Getting error when I try to change output directory using maven and pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven

Hi I'm having this problem: I have created a pom.xml and now I want export some dependencies in a particular folder. The pom.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--

This file is part of JEMMA - http://jemma.energy-home.org
(C) Copyright 2013 Telecom Italia (http://www.telecomitalia.it)

JEMMA is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) version 3
or later as published by the Free Software Foundation, which accompanies
this distribution and is available at http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html

JEMMA is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) for more details.


-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.energy-home</groupId>
<artifactId>jemma</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.2</version>
<name>JEMMA</name>

<properties>
<main.dir>${project.basedir}</main.dir>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<!--successfuttly moved to local repo -->
<org.eclipse.equinox.ds.version>1.1.1</org.eclipse.equinox.ds.version>
<org.eclipse.equinox.device.version>1.0.100</org.eclipse.equinox.device.version>
<org.eclipse.osgi.version>3.5.2</org.eclipse.osgi.version>
<org.eclipse.core.jobs.version>3.4.100</org.eclipse.core.jobs.version>
<org.eclipse.osgi.services.version>3.2.0</org.eclipse.osgi.services.version>
<org.eclipse.osgi.util.version>3.2.0</org.eclipse.osgi.util.version>    
<org.apache.commons.logging.version>1.1.1</org.apache.commons.logging.version>
<org.eclipse.equinox.util.version>1.0.100</org.eclipse.equinox.util.version>
<org.eclipse.equinox.cm.version>1.0.100</org.eclipse.equinox.cm.version>
<org.eclipse.equinox.event.version>1.1.101</org.eclipse.equinox.event.version>
<org.apache.xerces.version>2.9.0</org.apache.xerces.version>
<org.apache.xml.resolver.version>1.2.0</org.apache.xml.resolver.version>
<org.apache.xml.serializer.version>2.7.1</org.apache.xml.serializer.version>
<javax.xml.version>1.3.4</javax.xml.version>
<org.eclipse.equinox.useradmin.version>1.1.100</org.eclipse.equinox.useradmin.version>
<org.eclipse.equinox.preferences.version>3.2.301</org.eclipse.equinox.preferences.version>
<org.eclipse.equinox.common.version>3.5.1</org.eclipse.equinox.common.version>
<org.apache.commons.codec.version>1.3.0</org.apache.commons.codec.version>
<jaxb-osgi.version>2.2.7</jaxb-osgi.version>
<jaxb-api-osgi.version>2.2.7</jaxb-api-osgi.version>
<stax-osgi.version>0.3.95</stax-osgi.version>
<javax.activation.version>1.1</javax.activation.version>
<org.apache.commons.httpclient.version>3.1.0</org.apache.commons.httpclient.version>
<org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.version>1.6.6</org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.version>    
<javax.servlet.version>2.5.0</javax.servlet.version>
<org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.version>1.0.200</org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.version>
<org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.version>1.0.200</org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.version>
<org.eclipse.equinox.http.servletbridge.version>1.1.100</org.eclipse.equinox.http.servletbridge.version>
<org.mortbay.jetty.server.version>6.1.23</org.mortbay.jetty.server.version>
<org.mortbay.jetty.util.version>6.1.23</org.mortbay.jetty.util.version>
<org.eclipse.equinox.registry.version>3.4.100</org.eclipse.equinox.registry.version>
<org.apache.felix.webconsole.version>3.1.8</org.apache.felix.webconsole.version>
<org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.event.version>1.0.2</org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.event.version>
<org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.memoryusage.version>1.0.2</org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.memoryusage.version>
<org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.upnp.version>1.0.0</org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.upnp.version>
<org.apache.commons.io.version>1.4</org.apache.commons.io.version>
<org.apache.commons.fileupload.version>1.2.2</org.apache.commons.fileupload.version>
<org.json.simple.version>1.1</org.json.simple.version>
<org.json.version>1.0.0</org.json.version>
<org.restlet.version>2.1.6</org.restlet.version>
<org.restlet.ext.xml.version>2.1.6</org.restlet.ext.xml.version>
<!--<com.noelios.restlet.version>1.1</com.noelios.restlet.version>
<com.noelios.restlet.ext.net.version>1.1</com.noelios.restlet.ext.net.version>-->
<edu.emory.mathcs.backport.version>1.2.0</edu.emory.mathcs.backport.version>
<org.apache.felix.scr.version>1.6.0</org.apache.felix.scr.version>
<org.slf4j.version>1.7.7</org.slf4j.version>
<commons.jabsorb.version>1.3.1</commons.jabsorb.version>
<maven.license.plugin.version>2.5</maven.license.plugin.version>
<maven.clean.plugin.version>2.5</maven.clean.plugin.version>
<felix.bundle.plugin.version>2.3.7</felix.bundle.plugin.version>

<!-- Internal dependencies version properties -->
<org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.hac.lib.version>3.1.4</org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.hac.lib.version>
<org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.hac.version>3.1.3</org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.hac.version>
<org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.felix.console.web.version>1.0.9</org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.felix.console.web.version>
<org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.m2m.device.version>1.2.15</org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.m2m.device.version>
<org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.hap.client.version>1.2.15</org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.hap.client.version>
<org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.utils.version>1.0.6</org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.utils.version>
<org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.energyathome.version>2.2.25</org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.energyathome.version>
<org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.adapter.http.version>2.0.2</org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.adapter.http.version>
<org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.configurator.version>1.0.7</org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.configurator.version>
<org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.device.zgd.version>1.1.15</org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.device.zgd.version>
<!--<org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.zgd.version>1.4.1</org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.zgd.version>-->
<org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.zigbee.version>2.1.26</org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.zigbee.version>
<org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.webui.base.version>2.0.12</org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.ah.webui.base.version>
<org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.javagal.version>2.0.1</org.energy-home.jemma.osgi.javagal.version>
<org.ops4j.pax.logging.version>1.7.2</org.ops4j.pax.logging.version>
<org.slf4j.version>1.7.7</org.slf4j.version>
</properties>

<modules>
<module>jemma.launch</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.hac.lib</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.configurator</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.utils</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.m2m.device</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.hac</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.hap.client</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.upnp.energyathome</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.io</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.javagal</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.javagal.rest</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.javagal.gui</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.javagal.json</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.felix.console.web</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.energyathome</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.greenathome</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.webui.base</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.webui.energyathome</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.webui.energyathome.demo</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.adapter.http</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.app</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.zigbee</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.zigbee.appliances.generic</module>
<module>jemma.osgi.ah.zigbee.appliances</module>
<!--<module>jemma.osgi.zgd</module>-->
<module>Distribution</module>
</modules>

<build>
<resources>
<resource>
<directory>.</directory>
<includes>
<include>OSGI-INF/**</include>
</includes>
</resource>
<resource>
<directory>./src/main/resources</directory>
<includes>
<include>**/*</include>
</includes>
</resource>
</resources>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${felix.bundle.plugin.version}</version>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<configuration>
<supportedProjectTypes>
<supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
<supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
<supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
</supportedProjectTypes>
<manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
<instructions>
<Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
<Bundle-ClassPath>{maven-dependencies}</Bundle-ClassPath>
</instructions>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<!-- Deprecated, now assembly plugins is used to esport dependencies

<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>copy-dependencies-package</id>
<phase>package</phase>
<goals>
<goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
<outputDirectory>${main.dir}/libs</outputDirectory>
<excludeGroupIds>org.energy-home</excludeGroupIds>
</configuration>
</plugin>

-->
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.6</source>
<target>1.6</target>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
<compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<configuration>
<descriptors>
<descriptor>src/assemble/bin.xml</descriptor>
</descriptors>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<!-- <plugin>
<groupId>com.mycila</groupId>
<artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${maven.license.plugin.version}</version>
<configuration>
<header>header.txt</header>
<properties>
<owner>Telecom Italia</owner>
<year>2010</year>
</properties>
<useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
<strictCheck>true</strictCheck>
<includes>
<include>**/*.java</include>
<include>**/*.xml</include>-->
<!-- When add an header to a xml schema the jaxb cannot parses it
<include>**/*.xsd</include>
--> 
<!-- </includes>
<excludes>
<exclude>**/README</exclude>
<exclude>src/test/resources/**</exclude>
</excludes>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>headers-add-and-check-package</id>
<phase>package</phase>
<goals>
<goal>format</goal>
<goal>check</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
<execution>
<id>headers-add-and-check-clean</id>
<phase>clean</phase>
<goals>
<goal>format</goal>
<goal>check</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>-->
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${maven.clean.plugin.version}</version>
<!-- <configuration>
<filesets>
<fileset>
<directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
<includes>
<include>.settings/</include>
<include>.project</include>
<include>.classpath</include>
<include>bin/</include>
<include>META-INF/</include>
<include>.svn/**/*</include>
</includes>
<followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
</fileset>
</filesets>
<verbose>true</verbose>
</configuration> -->
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>localRepository</id>
<name>Local repository</name>
<url>http://130.192.85.149:8888/maven</url>
</repository>
<repository>
<id>maven-Jaxb</id>
<name>JAXB-NamespacePrefixMapper-Interfaces</name>
<url>http://mvnrepository.com/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
<id>maven-restlet</id>
<name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
<url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.equinox</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.ds</artifactId>
<version>${org.eclipse.equinox.ds.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.osgi</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi.util</artifactId>
<version>${org.eclipse.osgi.util.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.core.jobs</artifactId>
<version>${org.eclipse.core.jobs.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.equinox</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.util</artifactId>
<version>${org.eclipse.equinox.util.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.equinox</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.device</artifactId>
<version>${org.eclipse.equinox.device.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>jaxb-osgi</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-osgi</artifactId>
<version>${jaxb-osgi.version}</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<!--For Logging-->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.ops4j.pax.logging</groupId>
<artifactId>pax-logging-service</artifactId>
<version>${org.ops4j.pax.logging.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.ops4j.pax.logging</groupId>
<artifactId>pax-logging-api</artifactId>
<version>${org.ops4j.pax.logging.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
<version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
<!-- http://www.captaindebug.com/2012/01/slf4j-dependencies-and.html#.U24JJnWSzqc-->
<exclusions>
<exclusion>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>   
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.ops4j.pax.confman</groupId>
<artifactId>pax-confman-propsloader</artifactId>
<version>0.2.3</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Now I want to change the outputdirectory to the following bundles:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.ds
org.eclipse.equinox.util
org.eclipse.equinox.device
```

For doing this I've added this tag `<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/myDirectory</outputDirectory>` in the tag depency like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.equinox</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.ds</artifactId>
        <version>${org.eclipse.equinox.ds.version}</version>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/myDirectory</outputDirectory>
    </dependency>
```

But it dosen't work and I get this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.energy-home:jemma:0.2 (/home/fabio/Scrivania/jemma/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Malformed POM /home/fabio/Scrivania/jemma/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'outputDirectory' (position: START_TAG seen ...</version>\n\t\t\t<outputDirectory>... @295:21)  @ /home/fabio/Scrivania/jemma/pom.xml, line 295, column 21 -> [Help 2]
```

This is the full stack error

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Malformed POM /home/fabio/Scrivania/jemma/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'outputDirectory' (position: START_TAG seen ...</version>\n\t\t\t<outputDirectory>... @295:21)  @ /home/fabio/Scrivania/jemma/pom.xml, line 295, column 21

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:636)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:585)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.energy-home:jemma:0.2 (/home/fabio/Scrivania/jemma/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Malformed POM /home/fabio/Scrivania/jemma/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'outputDirectory' (position: START_TAG seen ...</version>\n\t\t\t<outputDirectory>... @295:21)  @ /home/fabio/Scrivania/jemma/pom.xml, line 295, column 21 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.io.ModelParseException: Unrecognised tag: 'outputDirectory' (position: START_TAG seen ...</version>\n\t\t\t<outputDirectory>... @295:21) 
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProcessor.read(DefaultModelProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:456)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:232)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:410)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:343)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:636)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:585)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: Unrecognised tag: 'outputDirectory' (position: START_TAG seen ...</version>\n\t\t\t<outputDirectory>... @295:21) 
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3ReaderEx.checkUnknownElement(MavenXpp3ReaderEx.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3ReaderEx.parseDependency(MavenXpp3ReaderEx.java:1721)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3ReaderEx.parseModel(MavenXpp3ReaderEx.java:2713)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3ReaderEx.read(MavenXpp3ReaderEx.java:4631)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3ReaderEx.read(MavenXpp3ReaderEx.java:4590)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:118)
    ... 23 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element "outputDirectory" is not allowed inside element "dependency".

outputDirectory - is a location of yor your compiled classes, and dependencies are usually jar files.

Now maven stores all dependencies in it's repository and only links dependencies to their locations in that repository. So it is not possible to change the location.

Perhaps You want your dependencies copied when the build is performed, you can use a plugin for that: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html